# Why was there a splash blood pattern behind his head?

Tags: 21-bridges

In the movie *21 Bridges*, Ray and Michael pay a visit to a money launderer to have new identifies forged and funds transferred. But the police start knocking on their door and shoot the money launderer in his eye through the peephole.

The money launderer did not die from his wound right away, he was pulled away and last seen alive while sitting on the floor with his back leaned against a concrete column.

But a few scenes later, this money launderer was seen dead and there was a splash blood pattern on the concrete column, right where he rested his back of his head.

Did someone shoot him in the head off-screen? You can see his body to the bottom right corner of the picture I attached.

[image: wide picture of a flat, which several character's standing and one dead]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The money launderer was alive when Michael and Ray left him.  Right after the cops who were outside the door broke through the door, you see 2 go screen right and 2 go screen left, while one guy walks straight towards the camera.  You hear a single gunshot come from screen left, which is the side of the apartment the money launderer was propped up on.  We know those cops were dirty, it's presumed they cleared the apartment no matter if the occupants were clean or dirty.  The next time you see the money launderer, there's a blood spatter behind him and he's dead.

Comment: Good observant. I missed it. All I remember is cops walking in.